# its any way of read a binary file and replace text in groovy like this python code?

Tags: python, groovy, replace, binary

I see this python code and I trying to know if exist any way of do this simple code in groovy

Please help me

```
f=open("header.fdf","rb")
s=str(f.read())
f.close()
s=s.replace(b'PatientName',name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> probably this will not work if the source file contains zero bytes

let's use mono-byte encoding to convert bytes to string and back

```groovy
def name = "The Beaver"
def s = new File("header.fdf").getText("ISO-8859-1").replaceAll("PatientName", name)
```

to convert it back to bytes:

```groovy
def bb = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")
/* write back to file */
new File("header.fdf").setBytes(bb)
```

Comment: Don't use UTF-8 then for a "binary" file.  Do the same as with python - go with some simple 8bit charset and hope for the best. I remain sceptical, that replacing text in a binary file is a great idea (assuming this is the form data PDF thingy)

Comment: @mightguy, use mono-byte encoding. for example `ISO-8859-1` (I've updated the answer). and if your file does not contain zero-byte then it will work.